# How to parse Input Object Date fields with format given in the object field itself

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a `Spring` project where in the controller method I have `@RequestBody Object obj` as one of the parameters.
Object have `Date` fields which with custom `JSON Serializer` and custom `JSON Deserializer` implemented using `@JsonDeserializer` and `@JsonSerializer` and the two classes.

When I send request to the controller method `Spring` calls the Jacksons deserialiser and deserialise string date field of Object into `Date`.

When deserialiser deserialise the date string and return the `Date` object I want it parse the string according to the format given in the Object's `format` field(i.e format is also given in the input) and create the `Date` object accordingly. How can this be implemented?

```
class MyObject{
    private String format; //field containing the format
    private Date currentDate;// this field should get formatted according to the 'format' field value

    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomJSONSerializer.class)
    public Date getCurrentDate(){
        return this.currentDate;
    }

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonDeserializer.class)
    public void setCurrentDate(Date currentDate){
        this.currentDate=currentDate;
    }
}


class CustomJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    //this format I want it to receive from the input as well i.e from the Object's format named instance variable.
    final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    try {
        return simpleDateFormat.parse(jp.getText());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //catch exception
    }
}
```

Can we use `JsonParser` or the `DeserializationContext` for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement deserialiser/serialiser for whole `MyObject` class to have access to all required fields. See below example:

```
public class MyObjectJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyObject> {
    @Override
    public MyObject deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        ObjectNode root = p.readValueAsTree();
        String format = root.get("format").asText();

        MyObject result = new MyObject();
        result.setFormat(format);

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try {
            result.setCurrentDate(dateFormat.parse(root.get("currentDate").asText()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(p, e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

You can use it:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyObjectJsonDeserializer.class)
public class MyObject {
```

Similarly, you can implement and register serialiser.